# Media Service API failed - 400 bad request - Creation of new Media Service accounts are not allowed as the resource has been deprecated

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-media-services

I can still create a media service manually, but not through the API because its "Deprecated" even though it isn't until June...

How can I get around this issue for my Terraform to succeed?

[image]

Ran terraform deployment, failed due to 400

> media.MediaservicesClient#CreateOrUpdate:
> Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 --
> Original Error:
> autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadRequest"
> Message="Creation of new Media Service accounts are not allowed as the resource has been deprecated."
> Details=[{"code":"MediaServiceAccountCreationDisabled","message":"Creation of new Media Service accounts are not allowed as the resource has been deprecated."}]

Comment: Are you trying to deploy this code from [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/media_services_account). @Adam Schultheis

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on this issue, I found that the resource Media services has been deprecated and complete deprecation is from June 2024. Refer [Azure Media Services retirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/) MS Doc for the relevant information.

Due to this, creating ams accounts through an API is also disabled.  I tried creating it using Portal, CLI as well as below terraforms resource but none of these are worked as shown below.

*Note*: Once this deprecation is done, it will migrate to AMS v3 for managing components and functionality.

*Portal:*

[image]

Terraform registry: [`azurerm_media_services_account`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/media_services_account)

*Terraform code:*

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "xxx"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "examplestoracck"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
}

resource "azurerm_media_services_account" "example" {
  name                = "samplemediaacck"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  storage_account {
    id         = azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    is_primary = true
  }
}
```

*Same error message when tried to deploy with above terraform configuration as well:*

[image]

*CLI:*

```bash
az ams account create --name mymediack --resource-group xxx --storage-account newblobjah
```

[image]

***If your requirement things permits, you may delay the creation of new AMS accounts(V3) until the deprecation date is done.***